# Command line: log in to MySQL and execute command in one line

Tags: mysql, command-line

I often find the need to check a table structure (to check column names for instance when writing a PHP script). My one single purpose is: speed. I use "Adminer" and in a few clicks I can check it out. But I want to do this faster, with a command line window I have always open anyway. So I'd like to create a function that allows me to do something like:

`mysql -uuser -ppassword && USE database; && DESCRIBE table;`

I would alias this in a way that I can call:

`describe database.table`

And voilá, I get the database structure. But my issue is: how can I log into MySQL AND run certain queries in one script?? I have not found a way to do this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
mysql database -uuser -ppassword -e "describe table;"
```

For example:

```
mysql -uuser -ppassword mysql -e "describe time_zone;"
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Time_zone_id     | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Use_leap_seconds | enum('Y','N')    | NO   |     | N       |                |
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

If you're looking for a way to alias this in your shell, you can use a function, like this:

```
function describe() { mysql -uuser -ppassword $1 -e "describe $2;"; }
describe mysql time_zone
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Time_zone_id     | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Use_leap_seconds | enum('Y','N')    | NO   |     | N       |                |
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 3):

Just an alternative method - rather than the `-e` flag, you can pipe in your query.  useful if the query is generated by some other process:

```
echo "DESCRIBE table;" | mysql -uuser -ppassword databasename
```

Or if you have a bunch of statements listed in a file like:

```
# File: statements.sql
DESCRIBE table;
SELECT col FROM table;
```

You can instruct mysql to read from the file:

```
mysql -uuser -ppassword databasename < statements.sql
```

Comment: I like that I can echo the command right into MySQL. That was helpful!